# Can I get the default hint color of an EditText?

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, hint

Is there a way to get the hint color from an EditText?

I need the color to set it as the text color of the EditText too

Comment: You should be able to tell what color the hint is in and then use it to set your textColor attribute!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you could use this:

```
final ColorStateList colors = editText.getHintTextColors();
editText.setTextColor(colors);
```

Note that hint color is actually a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html).

Answer (score 3):

Late response (but worth it). You can use:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorHint" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `getHintTextColors()` API. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getHintTextColors%28%29) documentation.